# Generate namespace from string

Tags: c++, namespaces

Functions under difference name spaces are needed, the name space reflects different data version, but the all the functions has the same signature. Please see example

```
For version v_1_0 this function is needed   v_1_0::decoder::decoding( ... )
For version v_1_1 then this shall be called v_1_1::decoder::decoding( ... )
```

I receives the version string from somewhere else. The version format is exactly as the namespace, I wonder if I could generated the function call from the namespace string variable.

The reason I'm asking for this question is, there are so many versions already and will be more added soon. I have to create a long if else or switch loop to call the function which is very annoying

```
switch (version) {
    case v_1_0:
        v_1_0::decoder::decoding( ... )
        break;
    case v_1_1:
        v_1_1::decoder::decoding( ... )
        break;
     ....
    default:
        break;
    }
```

Would be nice to have something like

```
auto name_space = get_namespace( version );
name_space::decoding( ... )
```

Comment: Does it have to be a namespace? Seems like you are looking for a simple interface.

Comment: A map of string to function pointers could be sufficient.

Comment: @Story Teller I didn't write the interface and that's what I get.

Comment: @mat seems I still need to create a long map and keep adding it when new version is made, but it is shorter than the switch loop

Comment: I have seen interface/API versioning using nest inline namespaces, I thought I understood it at the time but no longer.  Maybe this hint will help produce an answer.

Comment: X-macros could make it more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done. Namespace names are discarded when you compile the program.

You also cannot have a variable of type namespace. If each version was a class, or an instance of a class, you could create a function that returns the appropriate instance - but that is not the case for namespaces.